# how do I reput the Gnome sound that sounds at the beginnig?

Tags: gnome, sound, login

when I installed the operating sistem, there was an option for this sound, but in that time I didn't want the sound be played. now I want it, then how do I put it again? help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U haven't mention version of Ubuntu u installed.

For 11.X Go to

```
Ubuntu Tweak -> Login Settings -> Play sound at login
```

For 10.X Check this [Reference](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-turn-offdownup-login-sound-when-ubuntu-gnome-startup)

Comment: it's 11.10 I need it.

Comment: @Alfredo U don't have **Ubuntu Tweak** ? If no then install it using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`